# SSRS Switch Statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have a matrix where I am calculating the Total depending on the other textbox value.

This is my expression which calculate Total. If any of the box contains "*"  value in SSRS.

This expression is applied on total =

```
=Switch((ReportItems!Textbox7.Value="*"), "*", Count(Fields!Q3_A_1.Value)>19, Count(Fields!Q3_A_1.Value))
```

However, this expression is applied to above textbox7

```
=(Switch(Count(Fields!Q3_A_1.Value)<5, "*", Count(Fields!Q3_A_1.Value)>5 , Count(Fields!Q3_A_1.Value)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit this to be more clear? Having part of your question in an image is not very helpful.

Comment: Is the `[Q3_A_1]` row always 1 row? If not, can you show more sample data for different scenarios.

Comment: Can you please specify your problem more precisely. No one will understand what is your problem,what you are doing right now and what you want to achieve

Comment: Based on their other questions, this user does not know how to properly use tablixes and groups, nor are they willing to learn.

Comment: Hey, I figured out in tablix how to fix this. Many thanks for helping me